# Updating a String In Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking to update a word in a number of strings for a particular column.

For example;

```
Update Column A = 'This is a line of text.'
To 'This is a string of text.'
```

Where Column A might appear a number of times in the DB. Obviously I can just say;

```
Update
    TABLE
Set
    A = 'This is a string of text.'
Where
    A = 'This is a line of text.'
```

But I'm curious to a nicer way of doing in, perhaps using regex? Something along the lines of;

```
Update
    TABLE
Set
    A = [First Part of A] + 'string' + [Second Part of A]
Where
    A = 'This is a line of text.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
A = REPLACE(A, 'string', 'line') WHERE A LIKE '%line%'
```

Comment: Way too obvious an answer. Thanks, Mate.